# Converting dropdown menu to select2

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables, jquery-select2

I am attempting to create a datatable where the user can filter the table using dropdown menus. The first dropdown menu "project_select" fills with all the unique values from a column of the data table. The second dropdown menu "hr_select" fills with values based on the user's selection from the "project_select" dropdown menu.

Currently, the dropdown menus are mapped to span elements in the html. I am looking to convert these span elements to select2.

This is my desired html code:

```
    <label for="project_select"></label><select id="project_select" class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 10%">
    <option></option>
</select>
    <label for="hr_select"></label><select id="hr_select" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" style="width:15%">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

However, when I try and replace the span elements with that desired HTML code.. it doesn't work.

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dfahsjdahfsudaf/nL6q21g9/16/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `<span>` elements in your Fiddle are irrelevant to using a S2 select. Here is a demo:  [https://jsfiddle.net/mj7hLd1f/](https://jsfiddle.net/mj7hLd1f/). To make this Fiddle, I took your Fiddle and I made 3 changes: (1) I added the S2 JS and CSS libraries; (2) I gave each of the `<select>` elements an ID; and then (3) I initialized the selects: `$('#project_s2').select2();` and `$('#hr_s2').select2();`. Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: From that point onward, there is a world of Select2 customizations that you can apply, of course. But my Fiddle is just the absolute basics.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to save my Fiddle - I updated the link in the first comment.

Comment: @andrewjames thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted my comments to an answer for future visitors to this question:

The steps needed to convert your standard selects to "Select2" selects are:

1. Add the required libraries to the page:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

2. Give IDs to each of the current `<select>` elements:

```
select = $('<select id="project_s2"><option value=""></option></select>');
```

and:

```
select = $('<select id="hr_s2" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');
```

3. Use those IDs to initialize Select2:

```
$('#project_s2').select2();
$('#hr_s2').select2();
```

The end result is:

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "0",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "10",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "B",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "0",

  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "B",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "20",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "C",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "20",

  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "C",
    "ID": "65",
    "HR": "100",
  },

];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    columns: [{
        data: "Project_Name"
      },
      {
        data: "ID"
      },
      {
        data: "HR"
      }
    ],
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns([0, 2]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var colIdx = column.index();
        var node;
        var select;
        if (colIdx === 0) {
          node = $('#project_select');
          select = $('<select id="project_s2" style="width: 40%"><option value=""></option></select>');
        } else {
          node = $('#hr_select');
          select = $('<select id="hr_s2" style="width: 20%" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');
        }

        select.appendTo($(node).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (colIdx === 0) {
              val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(val);
              column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
              rebuildPositionSelect();
            } else {
              var vals = val.map(x => $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(x)).join('|');
              column.search(vals ? '^' + vals + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>')
        });

      });
      $('#project_s2').select2();
      $('#hr_s2').select2();
    }
  });

  function rebuildPositionSelect() {
    var select = $('#hr_select select').empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
    var column = table.column(2, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    column.search('').draw();
    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
      select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div style="margin: 20px;">

      <div>
        <span>Project: </span>
        <span id="project_select"></span>
        <span> HR: </span>
        <span id="hr_select"></span>
      </div>

      <br><br>

      <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project_Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>HR</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned in the comments, this is a very basic set-up for each Select2 drop-down.

To customize them further you can provide options - for example:

```
$('#project_s2').select2( { 
  theme: "classic",
  placeholder: 'Select an option'
} );
```

**Final Note:**

The use of basic `<span>` elements in the above example, only minimal layout/styling may be insufficient for your needs. So, you will probably want to provide CSS customizations which provide a better overall layout. But those changes should not affect your Select2 elements.

For example, adding in `style="width: 40%"` (as shown above) makes a difference - but that may not be what you want, in your specific case.